# How to enforce a specific timezone ignoring system time

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

I am trying to convert an ISO date to EST, so that the user always sees EST, regardless of the system.

Like so

`luxon.DateTime("2023-04-16T03:00:00Z").setZone("EST").toFormat('ttt')`

Yet it always comes out like so:

`10:00:00 PM GMT-5`

I want:

`10:00:00 PM EST`

What am I doing wrong? I know EST is IANA compliant.

Comment: Assuming that EST participates in daylight saving, isn't `10:00:00 PM EST` (w/o a date) ambiguous?

Comment: You are 100% correct. Sorry what I didn't mention is the date is there as well, but wanted to focus on the time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output in the format you desire (e.g., "10:00:00 PM EST"), you can use the `setLocale` method in combination with `toFormat`.

```
var result = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("2023-04-16T03:00:00Z")
  .setZone("America/New_York")
  .setLocale('en-US')
  .toFormat('hh:mm:ss a z');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: As this does work it gives me EDT since the US practices daylight savings. The client only wants to see EST, however something like America/Panama wont work because the timezone is fed in from the BE … I would say just add it but there are hurdles to hop over. Anyway TL;DR is there another way? haha

Comment: Try change like `setZone("Etc/GMT+5")`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't trivial, for a couple reasons. First "EST" is not an IANA zone. Second, it doesn't totally make sense: "EST" roughly means "US Eastern time and also it is not currently DST", which of course is dependent on the latter actually being true. You are asking for it to say "EST" even when it is not actually EST.

The other answer pointed out that you could just use "Etc/GMT+5" (you can also just use `{ zone: -5 * 60 }`) which will give you the right time, but then it won't format out "EST" when you print out the date, since it's not actually in the zone where "EST" is valid (there other other places besides the US on UTC-5).

That leaves us with writing a custom zone.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

class AlwaysEST extends luxon.Zone {
  get type() {
    return "always est";
  }
  
  get name() {
    return "EST"
  }
  
  get isUniversal() {
    return true;
  }
  
  offsetName(_, opts) {
    return opts.format == "long" ? "Eastern Standard Time" : "EST";
  }
  
  formatOffset(_, format) {
    switch(format) {
      case "narrow": return "-5";
      case "short": return "-05:00";
      case "techie": return "-0500";
      default: "-05:00";
    }
  }
  
  offset(_) {
    return -5 * 60
  }
  
  equals(other) {
    return other && other.type == "always est";
  }
  
  get isValid() {
    return true;
  }

}

const customZone = new AlwaysEST();

console.log(DateTime.fromISO("2023-08-06T10:00:00-04:00", { zone: customZone }).toFormat("ttt"));
console.log(DateTime.fromISO("2023-08-06T10:00:00-04:00", { zone: customZone }).toFormat("tttt"));
console.log(DateTime.fromISO("2023-01-06T10:00:00-05:00", { zone: customZone }).toFormat("ttt"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.4/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```